# Merging multi-index dataframes based on similar groups/indexes

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, merge

I have a multi-index dataframe that contains some economic and social indicators
A sample dataframe can be generated by this code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
arrays = [['USA', 'USA', 'Egypt', 'Egypt', 'U.S.A.', 'U.S.A.', 'ARE, eg', 'ARE, eg', 'United States', 'France', 'France', 'France'],
[1950, 1980,1980, 2010, 2010, 1990, 1960, 1990, 2015, 1980, 1995, 2010]]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*arrays)), names=['Country', 'Year'])
cols= ['ind1', 'ind2', 'ind3', 'ind4']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(12, 4), index=index2, columns=cols)
df.iloc[1::4,0] = np.nan; df.iloc[2::4,1] = np.nan; df.iloc[::3,2] = np.nan; df.iloc[1::3,3] = np.nan

df
```

Here is a sample output:

[image]

The problem is that the dataframe contains many typo-like keys in the dataframe index. for example, the USA is entered once as USA, U.S.A., US, or United States, etc.
I want to merge these groups based on a list that contains possible names, where the values of the columns are merged (as average value if repeated) and sorted.

```
new_names={'USA':['USA', 'U.S.A.', 'US', 'United States'],
'Egypt': ['Egypt', 'ARE', 'Egypt, the Arab Republic of',  'ARE, eg']}
```

How can I perform this merge efficiently in this multi-index pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could do it like this:

First, let's "invert" that dictionary to get it to the appropriate format for `rename` method in pd.dataframes.

```
rename_dict = {}
for k,v in dfnew_names.items():
    for item in v:
        rename_dict[item]=k
```

Second, let's rename indexes in the dataframe using the reformatted dictionary and sort.

```
df.rename(index=rename_dict).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
                  ind1      ind2      ind3      ind4
Country Year                                        
Egypt   1960  0.964161       NaN       NaN -0.909796
        1980 -0.568132       NaN -1.018460  2.295120
        1990  0.185795 -0.517331  1.276134       NaN
        2010  0.067946  0.895027       NaN  2.141615
France  1980       NaN  0.124058       NaN  1.377971
        1995 -2.153890       NaN  1.334341       NaN
        2010  0.019129  0.807188  0.804133 -0.698463
USA     1950 -0.023521  0.432706       NaN -0.701396
        1980       NaN  0.824445  1.027330       NaN
        1990       NaN  0.848902 -1.537311 -0.624271
        2010  0.641681 -0.504838 -1.383700       NaN
        2015  0.688233 -0.277385  2.036573 -0.821976
```

Update if you have multiple years the use `groupby`

```
df.rename(index=rename_dict).groupby(level=[0,1]).mean()
```

Or, you can use `mean` with `level` parameters (this is the better way):

```
df.rename(index=rename_dict).mean(level=[0,1]).sort_index()
```

Comment: Many thanks for that, but, what if the years are repeated, how to add the "mean" aggregation function?

Comment: @MohammadElNesr See updated.  You'll need to use groubpy.

Comment: Thanks again, But the last line (using mean with level), leads to unsorted dataframe. Can we add groupby or sort with it?

Comment: You can just add sort_index() after mean level. `df.rename(index=rename_dict).mean(level=[0,1]).sort_index()`  Updated solution.